# Python crash with pyHook.HookManager() on KeyDown [ctrl]+[c]

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pyhook

I am creating a python script to record the keys that I press across my system (keylogger) and call home with information on what my typing habits are. I am new to python and I am using this application to learn about it. I am using python-3.x and windows 8

Full source code can be found here 
https://github.com/funvill/QSMonitor/blob/master/monitor.py

Using this snippet I am able to record all the keypress across my entire system. The problem is when I [ctrl]+[c] to copy something in another window the python code crashes.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Run the monitor.py script
2. In another window (notepad.exe) type a few letters (abcd).
3. Highlight the letters in notepad and hold down [ctrl] and press [c]

**Experienced:**

An windows error message would pop up and tell me that the python.exe has stop functioning and would need to be restarted. No python error message was in the command window.

```
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    global keyDatabase
    global keyLoggerCount 
    keyLoggerCount += 1 

    # http://code.activestate.com/recipes/553270-using-pyhook-to-block-windows-keys/ 
    print ('MessageName:',event.MessageName )
    print ('Message:',event.Message)
    print ('Time:',event.Time)
    print ('Window:',event.Window)
    print ('WindowName:',event.WindowName)
    print ('Ascii:', event.Ascii, chr(event.Ascii) )
    print ('Key:', event.Key)
    print ('KeyID:', event.KeyID)
    print ('ScanCode:', event.ScanCode)
    print ('Extended:', event.Extended)
    print ('Injected:', event.Injected)
    print ('Alt', event.Alt)
    print ('Transition', event.Transition)
    print ('---')    

    # check to see if this key has ever been pressed before 
    # if it has not then add it and set its start value to zero. 
    if event.Key not in keyDatabase:
        keyDatabase[ event.Key ] = 0 ; 

    # Incurment the key value 
    keyDatabase[ event.Key ] += 1 ; 
    return True

# When the user presses a key down anywhere on their system 
# the hook manager will call OnKeyboardEvent function.     
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()

while True : 
    pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
```

**My question is:**

- What could be causing this crash on copy and past?

Answer (score 1):

In python, Ctrl+C throws a KeyboardInterrupt exception.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: How would I resolve this issue? I tried adding Try and except blocks around the main application loop with out success.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch `KeyboardInterrupt` exceptions, you could use a nested loop. This way when a KeyboardInterrupt occurs, the program exits only the inner loop.

```
while True:
    try:
        while True:
            pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```