# pyHook for Python 3.3

Tags: python, keylogger, pyhook

I am coding a simple keylogger using Python. I hope to use pyHook to capture keyboard events.I couldn't find any packages of pyHook for python 3.3 which I have installed. Is there any other module for python 3.3 which provides similar functionalities?

Comment: I suppose using a previous version of Python is out of the question?

Comment: Do you need to use a binary package, instead of, say, installing MinGW or Visual Studio Express and [building it from source](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=PyHook_Build_Instructions)? I haven't tried building it for 3.x, but in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449956/python-crash-with-pyhook-hookmanager-on-keydown-ctrlc) it looks like the OP has done it.

Comment: I tried to install it with .exe. But it asks me for python 2.7. I want to use pyHook with current installation of python instead of moving to an older version of python

Comment: There are separate .exe installers for each version of Python. That's how all binary installers work (at least for packages that have C/SWIG/etc. extension code). So, you can't use the 2.7 installer with 3.3. But you can install from source.

Answer (score 6):

A quick google turned up [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook), which has unofficial installers for pyHook 1.5.1 (and a whole lot of other packages) for Python 3.3. I haven't tested it, but it seems worth trying. And there are a couple of other similar repositories on the first page of Google results if this one doesn't work.

I also found a few forks on `github`, like [this one](https://github.com/Answeror/pyhook_py3k), which have fixes for Unicode bugs in 3.x. I have no idea if those bugs have been fixed in the main `pyHook` project (or made it into the 1.5.1 release), but if you run into problems, you may want to take a look.

You'd have a lot more options if you installed a compiler (MinGW and/or Visual Studio Express) and used `easy_install` or `pip` to install packages automatically, building them from source if necessary. Then you wouldn't need to search for binary installers for everything.

Answer (score 0):

The inofficial installers mentioned by abarnert seem to work fine. They provide installers for almost every version of Python - except for 3.5, which is currently considered unstable anyway (07/10/14), so that's not a big issue.