# How can I install pyhook for Python 3.3?

Tags: python, installation, pip, pyhook

I have tried using pip but I get the following error:

Requirement 'pyHook-1.5.1-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist

I am copying the exact filename yet I still get this error, I cannot just use pip install pyhook, it returns that there is no supported version for 3.3.

I got the whl from this site:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15920534/1281947) useful.

Comment: That is the place I got the whl from, they replaced all exe installers with whls - Yet pip seems to fail to install the whl

Comment: I think the more useful part of that answer is the part explaining how to avoid downloading installers at all.

Comment: As I said in my question, pip doesnt seem to work for installing the whl.  I tried easy_install and it returned:

No local packages or download links found for pyHook
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pyHook')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install pyHook package "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyHook"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895493/cant-install-pyhook-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requir)